# Cannot configure Resharper to allow abbreviations as a parameter name

Tags: resharper, naming, abbreviation

I am trying to get resharper to accept "ID" as an allowable abbreviation when used in an parameter list, yet it seems to ignore the abbreviation and complain about inconsistent naming with the message...

> "Name 'ID' does not match rule 'Parameters'. Suggested name is 'id'."

... for a method signature like

```
GetThisSpecificEntity(int? ID, string uniqueEntityName);
```

... but does not generate a message for signatures like this...

```
GetThisSpecificEntity(int? entityID, string uniqueEntityName);
```

Trying to change the abbreviations list to include "ID" does not stop this from popping up, and changing parameter naming options to allow "ID" as prefix or suffix seems to causes other conflicts and weirdness with the default 'Parameters' rule elsewhere in code.

I'm not looking to debate usage of "ID" (Identity) vs "Id" (Ego) as part of this, as it seems to be a problem for any parameter that is added into the abbreviations list. I have about a dozen domain-specific abbreviations - "AII", "SAP", "PLC", etc - that I've added to reduce the noise generated by legacy code, and I simply want to have this abbreviation honored in parameter lists. Is there a way to make this work the way I need it to?

Comment: The same thing happens with standalone variables: `var ESIID = 0;` gets the curly blue underline and message even though 'ESIID' is in the abbreviations list.